# How to save variable values when leaving activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to implement two mwthods to save variable informaton after I leave the activity,but I'm getting an error: `markOne cannot be resolved to a variable` on each of the variables.I have placed the two methods outside of OnCreate() .I have posted the whole class below showing how I  implemented the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods.Could someone show me why the variales are not being resolved? I'm guessing its because the variables can't be accessed outside of onCreate() but how would I fix this problem?

```
public class CalcResult extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView result1,result2,result3;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        final Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class);
        final Intent intent2=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final Intent intent3=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);



        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.a,
                null);

        // Set up your ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        // You customization
        final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

        final Button actionBarHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        actionBarHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent2);

            }

        });

        final Button actionBarInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_staff);
        actionBarInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_help);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent1);

            }

        });


        final Button actionBarHoome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_home);
        actionBarHoome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appicon);
        actionBarHoome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHoome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent3);

            }

        });

        result1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.markOne);
        result2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.markTwo);
        result3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.markThree);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
        double markTwo = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);
        double markThree = intent.getDoubleExtra("number3", 0);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        result1.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(markOne)+"mm"));
        result2.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(markTwo)+"mm"));
        result3.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(markThree)+"mm"));

    }

    //Two methods I'm trying to implement ->
    @Override
    protected final void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
    {
        // Save variables.
        outState.putString("markOne", markOne);
        outState.putString("markTwo", markTwo);
        outState.putString("markThree", markThree);

    }

    @Override
    protected final void onRestoreInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
    {
        // Restore saved variables and reshow activities if they were open.
        markOne = outState.getString("markOne", "");
        markTwo = outState.getString("markTwo", "");
        markThree = outState.getString("markThree", "");

    }

}
```

Comment: Declare `markOne`,`markTwo` and `markThree` like you declared your `TextViews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define global variable below line

```
TextView result1,result2,result3;
double markOne,markTwo,markThree;
```

and replace

```
double markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
double markTwo = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);
double markThree = intent.getDoubleExtra("number3", 0);
```

with

```
markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
markTwo = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);
markThree = intent.getDoubleExtra("number3", 0);
```

Comment: I implemented these methods now,but the values are still cleared when I go back to the activity.Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you finish that activity and after that going back in that then it will definately clear..so dont finish your current activity when going in another activity from that.

Comment: I don't call `finish` just startActivity but the values are still being cleared..Are you sure I don't have to call the stored values again when I have navigated back?

Comment: if you going to another activity from the current one, then nothing will cleared. there is no need to store anything..